# How to limit texture size for whole project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3d for developing games.

In project exists many textures.

How to limit texture size for whole project?

Comment: I recommend installing a spellchecker plugin for your browser. Also please [do not add tags to your question titles](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A183527+[unity3d]), there are already tags for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to limit the size of your imported textures by default, there is no direct way of doing that, other than editing the max size after import. The default there will always be 1024.

You can however write a custom [AssetPostProcessor](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html) which (despite its name) also has an [OnPreprocessTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.OnPreprocessTexture.html) method which you can use to set import settings. A very bare bones example would be something like this:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class DefaultTextureSizer : AssetPostprocessor 
{

    void OnPreprocessTexture ()
    {
        TextureImporter tex_importer = assetImporter as TextureImporter;
        tex_importer.maxTextureSize = 512; //Some other max size than the default
    }

}
```

That will make sure all imported textures will have a maximum size of (in this case) 512.

Comment: I just can't believe Unity still hasn't added a simple Default Import settings in the Project Settings for the entire project, it's so obvious that most people developing for mobile will almost never use 4096 textures for example and if they do in some cases they could just specify for those few cases. Instead, we have to either wait hours just to import new assets with giant textures and then reimport them with the smaller max size, or we have to mess with scripting, and figure out the hard way. And this is at least 6 years after the first threads appeared asking for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `OnPostprocessTexture` you can read the actual size of each texture and set the maximum size.

I use this code when I want to lower the resolution of textures for low-end phone builds:

```
    public void OnPostprocessTexture(Texture2D texture)
    {
        if (!TextureResizingEnabled)
            return;

        TextureImporter textureImporter = assetImporter as TextureImporter;
        TextureImporterFormat format;

        TextureImporterSettings textureImporterSettings = new TextureImporterSettings();
        textureImporter.ReadTextureSettings(textureImporterSettings);

        //grabbing the max texture dimension for use in size calculation
        float size = Mathf.Max(texture.width, texture.height);

        Debug.LogError("original size = " + size + "  orig max size = " + textureImporterSettings.maxTextureSize);

        // Getting the smallest texture size between original texture size, to be resized  by TextureResizingFactor, and maxTextureSize set in asset importer settings:
        size = Mathf.Min(Mathf.Pow(2f, Mathf.Floor(Mathf.Log(size, 2f)) - TextureResizingFactor), textureImporterSettings.maxTextureSize);

        Debug.LogError("chosen   size = " + size);

        // we won't make any changes if the calculate size is lesser than the minimum on Unity dropdown box (32):
        if (size >= 32)
        {
            textureImporterSettings.maxTextureSize = (int)size;
            textureImporter.SetTextureSettings(textureImporterSettings);
        }
    }
```

It basically divides by 2 the maximum texture size, so if you have a texture with maximum size equals to 2048 it will set to 1024, while a 512 texture in the same project will be set to 256. This is very useful to lower the memory usage.

The disadvantage of using `OnPostprocessTexture` in this case is that I must reimport the textures twice: the first will change the texture max size, and the second (with this piece of code disabled) will actually apply the new max size. This happens because we are setting the new size after the texture was imported, but it's the only way since there is no way to read a texture size in `OnPreprocessTexture`.